# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\prash\\Desktop\\DS_examples\\battles.csv')
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
df["major_death"] = df["major_death"].fillna(1.0)
df["year1"] = df["year"].astype('int32')
x = df["year1"]
y = df["major_death"].astype('int32')

example_one = sns.barplot(x, y)
#example_one = sns.barplot(x="year", y="major_death", data=df )

plt.show()
```

When I run the above code I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

In order to overcome the error I did typecasting. But it didn't help me. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You really shouldn't be downcasting from `int64` to `int32` - instead you should just work with `int64`. Do you still get the error without the uses of `.astype('int32')`?

Comment: Yes, i am still having the issue even after using .astype('int32')